# Issues with installing CiviCRM onto a Drupal 9 instance

Tags: installation, drupal-9

I am currently having issues trying to install CiviCRM onto a Drupal 9.3.14 instance for a NPO website which is currently utilising the LocalGov Drupal Install Profile (https://www.drupal.org/project/localgov).

We are currently using a managed hosting service and have no SSH access to be able to install via composer. (I have emailed them and they will not provide us with access). I have tried to install via the "Add a module" method however it doesn't recognise the CiviCRM Drupal file and keeps showing an error "does not contain any .info.yml files.".

Is it possible to install CiviCRM without SSH access?

Setup Drupal Version: 9.3.14
Web Server: nginx1.14.2
PHP Version: 8.1.6 (Memory limit 256M)
Database Version: 10.6.7-MariaDB

Many thanks

Comment: There are two ways of answering this question: technically, and strategically. Technically it may be possible, but strategically, it's almost certainly a bad idea, because it'll be a bear to keep up to date. If your provider doesn't provide the tools to install civicrm properly, you'll almost certainly run into all kinds of grief after installation as well. Sounds like your provider doesn't understand or want to understand how civicrm is different from a Drupal module.

Comment: I'm assuming you've also asked them if they are willing to install and manage your civicrm install?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

- back up the site and files
- copy the files to a local drive on your computer
- do the commands to download the civi files
- use the hosting provider's control panel to replace the files on the server
- now install the module in the UI